# Node.js app not deploying correctly on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, npm

My repository: https://github.com/jacklemasters/tech-blog

The app works locally on my machine, but I cannot seem to figure out why it will not work on Heroku. I have attempted completely moving the code, a new repository, nothing seems to help.

Here are the error logs I am receiving from Heroku:
2021-10-04T14:32:52.833339+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tech-blog@1.0.0 start: node server.js
2021-10-04T14:32:52.833414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-10-04T14:32:52.833484+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-10-04T14:32:52.833533+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the tech-blog@1.0.0 start script.
2021-10-04T14:32:52.833601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-10-04T14:32:52.847732+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-04T14:32:52.847831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-10-04T14:32:52.847916+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-04T14_32_52_834Z-debug.log
2021-10-04T14:32:53.006395+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-04T14:32:53.089213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

edit: I understand it could be something with my packages, but on my side I see them as installed. Still at a loss!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If possible you should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using libraries that you didn't import into the package.json with npm.

Example: `npm install express-session`

Other thing that is wrong is to upload the .dotenv file to GitHub. Use the .gitignore to avoid it and configure the heroku envorinment variables. See more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: this would make sense considering I kept moving the files and reinstalling. Is there a difference between just writing npm install express-session with and without the --save? I only ask because I had never seen that before. I will be home to try this in a few hours and let you know if it worked. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Your welcome. Try to reinstall all your packages using npm and make sure that they are imported into the package.json.
About the  --save, your are right,  is no longer needed afer npm version 5.0.0. It was needed to inject the module into the package in the past.

Comment: I finally had the attempt to try this, and still getting the same error. Is there something I am missing? I see the dependencies on my package.json.. Tried installing them once again anyways, still running into the same issue!

Comment: Should have added.. Here are new errors. https://imgur.com/a/mj2tMuA